# How to remove rows based on level frequency?

Tags: r

I have a frame like this:

```
 ---------------------------------
| keyword | has_a | has_b | has_c |
|---------+-------+-------+-------|
| a; b    |   1   |   1   |   0   |
| c       |   0   |   0   |   1   |
| a       |   1   |   0   |   0   |
| a       |   1   |   0   |   0   |
| b       |   0   |   1   |   0   |
| b       |   0   |   1   |   0   |
 ---------------------------------
```

I would like to remove the rows that have keywords that only appear once. For instance, in the example above, I would want to remove the row with `c`, but not the row with `a; b`.

I found that by running `summary` I can get the means of the binary columns. The means of those keyword columns who only appear once is `0.0006009615` (there are 1664 rows).

Is there a way to remove factor levels based on this mean? What if I wanted to remove all rows whose keyword frequency was 1 through 5 (0.003004808 - 0.0006009615)?

Comment: can you comment on how this differs from your other recent question?

Comment: @BenBolker In the other question I asked removed rows based on the levels being unique. After accomplishing that, I realized it was deleting (from the example above) `a; b` rows also because they were scarce, but in fact those keywords appear a lot, but separately.

Comment: @BenBolker So in the example above `c` appears once for 6 rows `1 / 6 = 1.67`. `a` and `b` appear three times: `3 / 6 = 0.5`. `a; b` also only appears once, but a and b both show up in more rows, so we should keep that.

Answer (score 3):

We split the `keyword` and get the frequency with `table` and use that to remove the rows:

```
 tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(df1$keyword, ";")))
 subset(df1, grepl(paste(names(tbl)[tbl>1], collapse="|"), keyword))
```

Comment: `Error in strsplit(df$keyword, ";") : non-character argument` also got the same error using "\\;"

Comment: check for case-sensitivity.  Your previous example had `Keyword` as the column name, this one has `keyword`.  Misspelling the column name will give a `NULL` result; `strsplit(NULL,";")` gives the "non-character argument" error (This is why reproducible examples are nice ...)

Comment: @BenBolker `tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(c3ch$Keywords, ";")))` checked and rechecked the name of the column is `Keywords`. Where could I post an example?

Comment: OK, try `strsplit(as.character(c3ch$Keywords),";")`  (apparently `factor` variables also give the same error message). Again: **reproducible example** ...